# Start the activity of my application from another application ( file explorer / download)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

Application I am currently building a simple image viewer application ( that you can view an image in)

Consider this scenario, you just downloaded an image from the internet and now you scroll to the image using file explorer ( which is built into the android phone) and press on "open with". Currently, there is a "Gallery" (built-in application) and other applications present when you press "open with" but my application is not present. How can I fix this? And how do I go about opening the image?

you can just consider the function that loads the image in my application to be
`imageViewer.loadImage(getIntent().getData()))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register an intent filter in your app's `AndroidManifest.xml` to notify the OS that your app is able to handle certain types of implicit intents. Read more in [Receiving an implicit intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#Receiving).

Answer (score 1):

Did you already include an `<intent-filter>` in your manifest for the activity you want to launch?  That is probably the simplest way.

See https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive